# Meaning of 一人付一半 in 车费我们俩一人付一半，怎么样？

Tags: meaning, expressions

In this sentence:

> 车费我们俩一人付一半，怎么样？

I don't fully understand the meaning of `一人付一半`.

I have found that `付一半` can mean "pay half", but `一人` confuses me (if it refers to one person, why is that form used instead of `一个人`?).

Comment: 一个人付一半 is also valid in this case

Comment: 一人付一半, each person pays half

Answer (score 14, accepted):

一人 can be thought of as 'per person' or 'each person'.

This grammatical construction is extremely common in Chinese. I think it's called topical construction (correct me if I am wrong here). Essentially, you have the topic of the sentence (bus/taxi fare) at the start, followed by the subject, verb and the rest of the object.

So let's break it down:

1. Topic: 车费 (bus/taxi fare - need more context to determine the exact
   nature)
2. Subject: 我们俩 (We [two])
3. Verb: 付 (to pay)
4. Object: 一半(车费) (half [of the fare])
5. Adverbial: 一(个)人 (each person, per person - alternative wording: 每(个)人)

Possible translations:

- We split the fare by paying half of it each.
- We both pay half the fare.
- Each of us pays for half the fare.

I missed the last bit of your question the first time around. The measure word 个 is omitted. It means the same whether it's in there or not (in this case). However, 一人 in this sense is also used in some set phrases (such as 一人做事一人当 - one is responsible for one's own actions), and in those cases, you cannot use 一个人 in its stead. Fivesheep's answer has enough examples to give you a good idea how often it's used.

Comment: is there a difference between 一人 and 个人 in this context?  Are they interchangeable?  (Ignoring the 我们俩 part which would make 个人 confusing).

Comment: Great answer. Worth noting that `一` is one of the most complicated morpheme in the language despite its simple meaning as word (and its look maybe). There are even theses discussing the syntax and semantics of `一X一Y` (http://cdmd.cnki.com.cn/Article/CDMD-10216-2010089251.htm).

Comment: @KangMing Not 个人 but 一个人, in which case, it is equivalent to 一人. The measure word 个 is omitted. That being said, however, in colloquial speech, you'd probably hear '个人' used in this context as well; just the speakers being lazy in my opinion.

Comment: @JamesJiao, if you hear `个人付一半` I believe it's actually `各人付一半`.

Comment: @NS.X. You are probably right :).

Comment: @deutschZuid, for the '个人' part, it is not right. '个人' means *an individual* or *personal*, which is rarely used in daily conversation to mean 'each person/per person'. For example: "个人意见" means "personal opinion", "个人所得税" means "individual income tax".

Comment: @NS.X. When you say "一半" or "half", it only refers to exactly 2 people, which "各人" or "各个人" in some contexts implies more than 2 people. It's even hard for me, a native speaker to explain how "各" and "每" is different, but the following sentences are more natural in daily conversations. 1. `每人各付一半` 2. `一人付一半`

Answer (score 2):

Each of us two pay half the fee, what do you think?

it's very common to say 一人..., e.g. 一人一个, 一人一次
there's also an idiom 一人做事一人当

Answer (score 0):

车费我们俩一人付一半，怎么样？

It is AA.

车费10元，一人付一半，就是每人5元。